# What is SwitchMap in RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Restangular in my Angular 5 project. In [addErrorInterceptor section](https://github.com/2muchcoffeecom/ngx-restangular#adderrorinterceptor), if you look at the code it calls the `refreshAccesstoken` method and then gets the new access token in `switchMap` part. By now I'm returning a `replySubject` in my `refreshAccesstoken` method so if I subscribe to the return value, I can get the new access token but I'm not able to get it in switchMap as I don't know what it is (I've also searched for switchMap but I just found some functions which didn't help me).

Here is my code for AuthService.refreshAccessToken:

```
refreshAccessToken() {
  let resultSubject: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject<any>();
  const url = this.AUTH_URL + 'oauth/token';
  const requestOptions = {
    headers: new Headers({
      authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(this.clientId + ':' + this.clientSecret),
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
  };
  const body = {
    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
    refresh_token: this.refreshToken,
    // scope: ''
  };
  let params = this.utilityService.convertObjectToURLParams(body);

  this._http.post(url, params.toString(), requestOptions).subscribe(
    response => {
      let result = response.json();
      // console.log('refreshed_access_token', result);
      this.accessToken = result.access_token
      this.refreshToken = result.refresh_token
      this.expireIn = result.expire_in
      resultSubject.next(this.accessToken);
    },
    error => {
      resultSubject.error(error);
    }
  );
  return resultSubject;
}
```

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to use a ReplySubject?
It seems you are using it just to emit the new access token.

If this is the case, and if I do not miss something, then you could reach the same result in a simpler way, like

```
refreshAccessToken() {
  const url = this.AUTH_URL + 'oauth/token';
  const requestOptions = {
    headers: new Headers({
      authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa(this.clientId + ':' + this.clientSecret),
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    })
  };
  const body = {
    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
    refresh_token: this.refreshToken,
    // scope: ''
  };
  let params = this.utilityService.convertObjectToURLParams(body);

  this._http.post(url, params.toString(), requestOptions).map(
    response => {
      let result = response.json();
      // console.log('refreshed_access_token', result);
      this.accessToken = result.access_token
      this.refreshToken = result.refresh_token
      this.expireIn = result.expire_in
      return this.accessToken;
    }
  );
}
```

Basically you just substitute `subscribe` with `map` and then it should work

Comment: That's right. I didn't know anything about `map`! So what `map` is related to? Observables? Promises? So I can learn more about it.